# How to execute a raw query with returning in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

I have a table **Ticket** that has the **id** (autoincremental), **ticket_number** (trigger that reads a sequence), **value** and **date** in Oracle. And I want to do the following:

```
INSERT INTO TICKET (value, date) values (100, TO_DATE('07-29-2015', 'mm-dd-yyyy')) returning ticket_number into :ticket_number;
```

I need to do this in raw SQL, but I don't know how to get the value in sqlalchemy. is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried this with a toy table in Postgres and it works, I think should be equivalent in Oracle, please let me know.

```
In [15]:

result = session.connection().execute("insert into usertable values('m6', 'kk2', 'Chile') returning username")
for r in result:
    print r
(u'm6',)
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT for Oracle**: the one way to do it that I've found is not very elegant. It would be using the raw connection underneath `SQLAlchemy` connection, something like:

```
In [15]:

from sqlalchemy.sql import text
import cx_Oracle
​
cur = session.connection().connection.cursor()
out = cur.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
par = { "u" : out }   ​
cur.prepare("insert into usertable values('m34', 'kk2', 'Chile') returning username into :u")
cur.execute(None, par)
​
print(out)
print(type(out))
print(out.getvalue())
​
​
<cx_Oracle.STRING with value 'm34'>
<type 'cx_Oracle.STRING'>
m34
```

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to create a `cx_oracle variable` instance, it is just not available in the api, see [docs](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/variable.html#varobj).

Then, there is no way to avoid creating the cursor, even if it works when you delegate more to `SQLAlchemy`:

```
In [28]:

from sqlalchemy.sql import text
import cx_Oracle
​
cur = session.connection().connection.cursor()
out = cur.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
par = { "u" : out }
​
q = text("insert into usertable values('m43', 'kk2', 'Chile') returning username into :u")
result = session.connection().execute(q, par)
print(par["u"])
print(out)
type(out)

​<cx_Oracle.STRING with value 'm43'>
<cx_Oracle.STRING with value 'm43'>
Out[28]:
cx_Oracle.STRING
```

Of course, you should close the cursor in this second case (in the first one, oracle closes it). The point that there is no way to create an instance like `out = cx_Oracle.STRING()`

As I say, it is not very elegant, but I don't think there is a way to create an equivalent variable in `SQLAlchemy`. It is something that the code handles internally. I would just go for the raw connection-cursor.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT2**: In the code above, added `out.getvalue()` as suggested. Thanks!

Comment: The difference in oracle [returning into](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm) clause is that it forces you to declare a variable to make the return to, and applying this would only return `*** DatabaseError: (DatabaseError) ORA-01008: not all variables bound`.

Comment: Ok. The point Postgres does not accept `returning into` (not even when you try to run it in `pgadmin`. I would try something like `session.connection().execute("insert into usertable values('m6', 'kk2', 'Chile') returning username into ?", result)`, but I can't test it in oracle right now I think

Comment: I've finally was able to try in oracle and indeed it does not work. In case it helps, `session.connection().execute("insert into usertable values('m6', 'kk2', 'Chile') returning username into :u", result)` inserts the register with no error, but afterwards I did not find the way to get back the result.

Comment: I've had the same issue. Based on checking the [source code](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/0766c80b9c02fdbad3203835ab850ad690f4c03b/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/oracle/zxjdbc.py#L69) I think that I have to declare the variable as a type, but I haven't give it a shot yet.

Comment: Did some trials but could not make it work. I think the key problem is, when you build the statement using the `returning` method, you get as an output an object of type `ReturningResultProxy`, and from there you can get the result. However, in a raw statement like yours, and in oracle, the result is just `ResultProxy`, which has no info about the parameters, even if you use `bindparam()`. Well, at least in the trials I did....

Comment: Updated the response. If you find a better solution, please post it!

Comment: The answer hits right on the spot. The only thing I would add is that to get the value you need to do `out.getvalue()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [execute](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.execute) command.
Something like this:

```
raw_SQL = "INSERT INTO TICKET (value, date) values (100, TO_DATE('07-29-2015', 'mm-dd-yyyy')) returning ticket_number into :ticket_number;"
connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute(raw_SQL)
```

Comment: I've tried this, but I get `*** DatabaseError: (DatabaseError) ORA-01008: not all variables bound`

Comment: Yes, but I need to declare the variable where it returns the value to which is why I think it throws that error.

Comment: Hm, to be honest I'm not quite sure how this is best done if you *have* to pass the raw SQL command. Would it be an option to create the trigger in sqlalchemy and hook it to a `DDL` event? [For more on DDL](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/schema.html#customizing-ddl)  Sorry for not being more of a help on this.