# sqlalchemy does not execute oracle after insert trigger

Tags: python, oracle, triggers, sqlalchemy

I have two tables called **movimiento** (id_operacion, id_pago, importe) and **ticket** (id_movimiento, id_localidad, nro_ticket, precio, impreso, id_movimiento_anterior) and the ticket table has an after insert trigger that assigns the **nro_ticket** value from a table called **funcion** that holds the sequence value.

Here's the before insert trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER "TICKETS4_TST"."TRG_B_I_TICKET" 
BEFORE INSERT ON TICKET REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  ticket NUMBER;
BEGIN
  ticket := OBTENER_NUMERO_TICKET(SUBSTR(:new.id_localidad,0,9));
  :new.nro_ticket := ticket;
END;
```

And the function that obtains the nro_ticket value:

```
create or replace FUNCTION obtener_numero_ticket (id_fun IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
nro_ticket NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT seq_ticket into nro_ticket FROM funcion where id_funcion = id_fun;
  RETURN (nro_ticket + 1);
END obtener_numero_ticket;
```

And here's the after insert trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER "TICKETS4_TST"."TRG_A_I_TICKET" 
AFTER INSERT ON TICKET REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE funcion SET seq_ticket = :new.nro_ticket WHERE id_funcion= SUBSTR(:new.id_localidad,0,9);
END;
```

This is the SQLAlchemy code:

```
sql_movimientos = """INSERT INTO movimiento (id_operacion, id_pago,
                                             importe)
                     VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')
                     RETURNING id_movimiento INTO :id_movimiento"""
sql_tickets = """INSERT INTO ticket (id_movimiento, id_localidad,
                                     precio, impreso,
                                     id_movimiento_anterior)
                 VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s',
                         '%s', '%s')
                 RETURNING nro_ticket INTO :nro_ticket"""

with db.session as session:
    try:
        cursor = session.connection().connection.cursor()
        nuevo_id_movimiento = cursor.var(NUMBER)
        nuevo_nro_ticket = cursor.var(NUMBER)
        print sql_movimientos % (
            movimiento.operacion, movimiento.pago, movimiento.importe)
        session.execute(sql_movimientos % (
            movimiento.operacion, movimiento.pago, movimiento.importe),
             {'id_movimiento': nuevo_id_movimiento})
        nuevo_id_movimiento = int(nuevo_id_movimiento.getvalue())
    except Exception, e:
        session.rollback()
        raise e

    try:
        print sql_tickets % (nuevo_id_movimiento,
            ticket.localidad.id, ticket.precio, ticket.impreso,
            ticket.movimiento_anterior)
        session.execute(sql_tickets % (nuevo_id_movimiento,
            ticket.localidad.id, ticket.precio, ticket.impreso,
            ticket.movimiento_anterior),
            {'nro_ticket': nuevo_nro_ticket})
        nuevo_nro_ticket = int(nuevo_nro_ticket.getvalue())
        print nuevo_nro_ticket
    except Exception, e:
        session.rollback()
        raise e
```

This is how sqlalchemy translates the queries:

```
INSERT INTO movimiento (id_operacion, id_pago,
                                                     importe)
                             VALUES ('639086', '566365', '100')
                             RETURNING id_movimiento INTO :id_movimiento
INSERT INTO ticket (id_movimiento, id_localidad,
                                             precio, impreso,
                                             id_movimiento_anterior)
                         VALUES ('5725976', '------------------', '100',
                                 '0', '')
                         RETURNING nro_ticket INTO :nro_ticket
17 << nro_ticket value
INSERT INTO movimiento (id_operacion, id_pago,
                                                     importe)
                             VALUES ('639086', '566365', '100')
                             RETURNING id_movimiento INTO :id_movimiento
INSERT INTO ticket (id_movimiento, id_localidad,
                                             precio, impreso,
                                             id_movimiento_anterior)
                         VALUES ('5725977', '-------------', '100',
                                 '0', '')
                         RETURNING nro_ticket INTO :nro_ticket
17 << nro_ticket value
INSERT INTO movimiento (id_operacion, id_pago,
                                                     importe)
                             VALUES ('639086', '566365', '100')
                             RETURNING id_movimiento INTO :id_movimiento
INSERT INTO ticket (id_movimiento, id_localidad,
                                             precio, impreso,
                                             id_movimiento_anterior)
                         VALUES ('5725978', '----------------', '100',
                                 '0', '')
                         RETURNING nro_ticket INTO :nro_ticket
17 << nro_ticket value
INSERT INTO movimiento (id_operacion, id_pago,
                                                     importe)
                             VALUES ('639086', '566365', '100')
                             RETURNING id_movimiento INTO :id_movimiento
INSERT INTO ticket (id_movimiento, id_localidad,
                                             precio, impreso,
                                             id_movimiento_anterior)
                         VALUES ('5725979', '--------------', '100',
                                 '0', '')
                         RETURNING nro_ticket INTO :nro_ticket
17 << nro_ticket value
INSERT INTO movimiento (id_operacion, id_pago,
                                                     importe)
                             VALUES ('639086', '566365', '100')
                             RETURNING id_movimiento INTO :id_movimiento
INSERT INTO ticket (id_movimiento, id_localidad,
                                             precio, impreso,
                                             id_movimiento_anterior)
                         VALUES ('5725980', '--------------', '100',
                                 '0', '')
                         RETURNING nro_ticket INTO :nro_ticket
17 << nro_ticket value
```

But if execute the same thing in the SQLDeveloper as an anonymous block I get the proper values:

```
declare
  id_movimiento number;
  nro_ticket number;
begin
INSERT INTO movimiento (id_operacion, id_pago,
                                                     importe)
                             VALUES ('639086', '566365', '100')
                             RETURNING id_movimiento INTO id_movimiento;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(id_movimiento);
INSERT INTO ticket (id_movimiento, id_localidad,
                                             precio, impreso,
                                             id_movimiento_anterior)
                         VALUES (id_movimiento, '------------------', '100',
                                 '0', '')
                         RETURNING nro_ticket INTO nro_ticket;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(nro_ticket);
INSERT INTO movimiento (id_operacion, id_pago, importe)
                             VALUES ('639086', '566365', '100')
                             RETURNING id_movimiento INTO id_movimiento;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(id_movimiento);
INSERT INTO ticket (id_movimiento, id_localidad,
                                             precio, impreso,
                                             id_movimiento_anterior)
                         VALUES (id_movimiento, '--------------------', '100',
                                 '0', '')
                         RETURNING nro_ticket INTO nro_ticket;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(nro_ticket);
INSERT INTO movimiento (id_operacion, id_pago,
                                                     importe)
                             VALUES ('639086', '566365', '100')
                             RETURNING id_movimiento INTO id_movimiento;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(id_movimiento);
INSERT INTO ticket (id_movimiento, id_localidad,
                                             precio, impreso,
                                             id_movimiento_anterior)
                         VALUES (id_movimiento, '---------------------', '100',
                                 '0', '')
                         RETURNING nro_ticket INTO nro_ticket;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(nro_ticket);
INSERT INTO movimiento (id_operacion, id_pago,
                                                     importe)
                             VALUES ('639086', '566365', '100')
                             RETURNING id_movimiento INTO id_movimiento;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(id_movimiento);
INSERT INTO ticket (id_movimiento, id_localidad,
                                             precio, impreso,
                                             id_movimiento_anterior)
                         VALUES (id_movimiento, '--------------------', '100',
                                 '0', '')
                         RETURNING nro_ticket INTO nro_ticket;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(nro_ticket);
INSERT INTO movimiento (id_operacion, id_pago,
                                                     importe)
                             VALUES ('639086', '566365', '100')
                             RETURNING id_movimiento INTO id_movimiento;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(id_movimiento);
INSERT INTO ticket (id_movimiento, id_localidad,
                                             precio, impreso,
                                             id_movimiento_anterior)
                         VALUES (id_movimiento, '---------------------', '100',
                                 '0', '')
                         RETURNING nro_ticket INTO nro_ticket;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(nro_ticket);
end;
```

Which outputs this:

```
5725981
17 << nro_ticket value
5725982
18 << nro_ticket value
5725983
19 << nro_ticket value
5725984
20 << nro_ticket value
5725985
21 << nro_ticket value
```

So I assume the problem is SQLALchemy, but I don't see why it doesn't work.

Comment: In your first code block you are hard coding the values of id_movimiento inserted into your ticket table, in the second code block you are using a variable.  In your code you show the trigger that updates the seq_ticket column of the funcion table, but now how the nro_ticket column of the ticket table is set (it's not part of your insert statement).  In SQL Developer your code is all executed in one session, is what about in SQLAlchemy? you are only showing the SQL statements involved, but not any of the surrounding code.

Comment: @Sentinel updated it. The reason I execute raw queries is because the **session.add** does not allow me to use **returning into**, like in my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709252/how-to-execute-a-raw-query-with-returning-in-sqlalchemy

Comment: In oracle triggers fire in the following order 1) All Before statement triggers 2) All before each row triggers 3) All after each row triggers 4) all after statement triggers.  In your case you have 2 and 3.  If SQL Alchemy is batching the updates which seems likely, then your after insert trigger won't fire until after all the before insert triggers have fired.  As a result multiple rows get the same nro_ticket value, and then the seq_ticket value gets updated multiple times to the same value. In SQLDev each statement is processed one at a time so the triggers fire as expected.

Comment: @Sentinel This is exactly what happens, and unfortunately the only way I was able to fix this (which I don't really want to call a "fix", more of a "short-term problem solver") is to commit each time I add values to the ticket transaction, which does not fully work like it was planned in the beginning. The problem is the session itself will not execute the trigger unless it commits into the database.

Comment: Leandro, situations like this are what database sequences are made for.

Comment: @Sentinel The thing is that I need to have the ability to modify the sequence any time I want because that's what the client needs.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your requirement to modify the sequence at any time?  You can use the [ALTER SEQUENCE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_2012.htm#SQLRF00817) command to modify sequences. For examples of updating sequences see [this](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:951269671592) Ask Tom article.

Comment: @Sentinel nro_ticket comes from the funcion table because each funcion has the value of the next ticket. If a client prints 100 tickets and then wants the value to go back to 1, I need to be able to modify that value. Or if it wants it to start at 1000. But the ticket table can contain same values, because the pk is id_localidad and id_movimiento. Does that make it more clear?

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've posted, for me it is not clear how you create `SQLAlchemy` `session`. Anyway, since to me your code looks fine, I've done a trial over an Oracle database and it works. This is how I've done it,

Created the 2 tables through `SQLAlchemy` (probably you've done it directly).

```
In [2]:

class Movimiento(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'movimiento'

    id_movimiento = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_operacion = Column(Integer)
    id_pago = Column(Integer)
    importe = Column(Integer)

In [3]:

class Ticket(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ticket'

    nro_ticket = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_movimiento = Column(Integer)
    id_localidad = Column(Integer)
    precio = Column(Integer)
    impreso = Column(Integer)
    id_movimiento_anterior = Column(Integer)
```

Created the sequences directly,

```
create sequence movimiento_seq;
create sequence ticket_seq;

create or replace trigger movimiento_trigger
  before insert on movimiento
  for each row
  begin
    select movimiento_seq.nextval into :new.id_movimiento from dual;
  end;

create or replace trigger ticket_trigger
  before insert on ticket
  for each row
  begin
    select ticket_seq.nextval into :new.nro_ticket from dual;
  end;
```

Then the session:

```
engine = create_engine('oracle://test:test@localhost:1521/orcl')

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Base.metadata.bind = engine

DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

session = DBSession()
```

Took your code and made it a function,

```
from cx_Oracle import NUMBER

sql_movimientos = """INSERT INTO movimiento (id_operacion, id_pago,
                                             importe)
                     VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')
                     RETURNING id_movimiento INTO :id_movimiento"""
sql_tickets = """INSERT INTO ticket (id_movimiento, id_localidad,
                                     precio, impreso,
                                     id_movimiento_anterior)
                 VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s',
                         '%s', '%s')
                 RETURNING nro_ticket INTO :nro_ticket"""

#with session as session:
def ins_mov_tick(movimiento, ticket):
    try:
        cursor = session.connection().connection.cursor()
        nuevo_id_movimiento = cursor.var(NUMBER)
        nuevo_nro_ticket = cursor.var(NUMBER)
        print sql_movimientos % (
            movimiento.id_operacion, movimiento.id_pago, movimiento.importe)
        session.execute(sql_movimientos % (
            movimiento.id_operacion, movimiento.id_pago, movimiento.importe),
             {'id_movimiento': nuevo_id_movimiento})
        nuevo_id_movimiento = int(nuevo_id_movimiento.getvalue())
    except Exception, e:
        session.rollback()
        raise e

    try:
        print sql_tickets % (nuevo_id_movimiento,
            ticket.id_localidad, ticket.precio, ticket.impreso,
            ticket.id_movimiento_anterior)
        session.execute(sql_tickets % (nuevo_id_movimiento,
            ticket.id_localidad, ticket.precio, ticket.impreso,
            ticket.id_movimiento_anterior),
            {'nro_ticket': nuevo_nro_ticket})
        nuevo_nro_ticket = int(nuevo_nro_ticket.getvalue())
        print nuevo_nro_ticket
    except Exception, e:
        session.rollback()
```

(You'll see also minor modifications since I'm using the classes `Movimiento` and `Ticket` created above, while you are using some more complex class structure).

And then every time I run the function I see the ticket number incrementing:

```
In [21]:

ins_mov_tick(movimiento, ticket)
INSERT INTO movimiento (id_operacion, id_pago,
                                             importe)
                     VALUES ('1', '2', '45')
                     RETURNING id_movimiento INTO :id_movimiento
INSERT INTO ticket (id_movimiento, id_localidad,
                                     precio, impreso,
                                     id_movimiento_anterior)
                 VALUES ('3', '17', '45',
                         '1', '4')
                 RETURNING nro_ticket INTO :nro_ticket
3

In [23]:

ins_mov_tick(movimiento, ticket)
INSERT INTO movimiento (id_operacion, id_pago,
                                             importe)
                     VALUES ('1', '2', '45')
                     RETURNING id_movimiento INTO :id_movimiento
INSERT INTO ticket (id_movimiento, id_localidad,
                                     precio, impreso,
                                     id_movimiento_anterior)
                 VALUES ('4', '17', '45',
                         '1', '4')
                 RETURNING nro_ticket INTO :nro_ticket
4
```

I did not create the table `funcion` or the trigger, since I don't think it matters for your problem.

Anyway, from this long explanation, I'm just trying to say that your code should be ok, and the only reason I figure out that it does not work for you is the way you must be handling the `session` (basically, since I don't really grasp how you do it, I don't see where is it coming from). Another possibility is that I've misunderstood everything.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem is that nro_ticket can't be an autoincremental value since I have to have the ability to change the sequence value. That's why I think the trigger does not execute.

Comment: Then, I'm a bit lost, in the second part of your post, when you say that you've run those inserts into `movimiento` and `ticket`, which triggers were you using?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to post the before insert trigger which obtains the nro_ticket sequence. I'll update it now.

Comment: Ok, finally I understand what you are trying to do.... I could test it more or less quickly since I have the setup ready, but, first, I'd like to ask you, can you get concurrent requests of a ticket? I guess so, and if you can, the mechanism you've implemented is not very robust, it may assign the same `nro_ticket` to 2 registers.

Comment: Does it really matter that `nro_ticket` is a list of consecutive numbers for every `funcion`? Could you just have a sequence as a `nro_ticket`? and then whenever you want to get the tickets for one `funcion` you can do it easily, you have the info in the ddbb. I think this would be more robust, you would not have to care about concurrency at all, the oracle sequence will handle it... else, if you really need consecutive ticket numbers, I would do it as a separate column, I would keep the sequence as the pk. But these are only suggestions, if you need to stick to what you have, just tell me

Comment: Yes, we do have concurrent requests and this is a known issue. The thing is that I don't have the resources (not enough oracle knowledge, time and clients' patience) to do a throughout examination of the trigger. I'll do it sometime soon in the future, and your suggestion is what I was thinking of, but at the moment I can't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86628/discussion-between-lrnzcig-and-leandro-poblet).